# Calculating goodness of fit and choosing the right model (R)

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit, regression-strategies

I'm trying to evaluate the value of an object, depending on his characteristics. In order to do this, I'm building the following regression model `price ~ .`, using similar objects and for each variable I got min 20 observations

I encountered following problem: none of the regression models worked for all my data, so I decided to use all of the followings methods:

```
model.lm <- lm(price ~ .)
model.lmLog <- lm(log(price) ~ .)
model.ltsReg <- ltsReg(price ~ .)
model.ltsRegLog <- lts(log(price) ~ .)
model.lmrob <- lmrob(price ~ .)
model.lmrobLog <- lmrob(log(price) ~ .)
model.lmRob <- lmRob(price ~ .)
model.lmRobLog <- lmRob(log(price) ~ .)
model.glm <- glm(price ~ .)
model.glmLog <- glm(price ~ ., family=gaussian(link="log"))
```

My question is: how can I decide which of this models fits best for the current data, without plotting the results?

As far as I know, the `r-squared` aren't trusty, because I the data is corrupted, so will be the `r-squared`.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**[UPDATE]**

what do you think about using `BIC` or `AIC` and choosing the one with the lowest value?

what do you think about choosing the variables for the regression upon the analysis of `anova`?

I have 17 variables from which 10 are dummy variables, is that a problem?

Answer (score 5):

When you entertain more than about 3 models, model uncertainty will greatly distort your final result, especially with regard to precision, confidence intervals, and $P$-values.  AIC is generally preferred over BIC, but AIC does not solve the above problem.  I would choose a robust semi-parametric model such as proportional odds or proportional hazards (see the `orm` function in the R `rms` package).  These are $Y$-transformation invariant.  Or use AVAS to make estimation of the transformation of $Y$ part of the process (function `areg.boot` in `rms`).  Note that with 20 observations you cannot afford to model more than a couple of parameters on the right hand side of the model, and any linearity assumptions you make in doing so are questionable.

Traditional robust regression involves trimming, mean absolute deviation (MAD) minimization, etc., and it is very dependent on how $Y$ is transformed.  Robust regression also, except for MAD (quantile regression) produces hard-to-interpret estimates.  A large class of ordinal regression models is based on cumulative probabilities and allows one to directly estimate any exceedance probability or other probability of interest.  It also allows you to estimate means, and in the case of continuous $Y$, quantiles.  In `rms` the pertinent functions are `orm`, `Quantile`, `Mean`, and `ExProb`, the latter 3 functions being applied to a fit object produced by `orm`.  A detailed case study may be found at the link to course handouts at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms and is covered in detail in the upcoming 2nd edition of my book *Regression Modeling Strategies*.  Except for the estimation of the conditional mean, ordinal regression in the cumulative probability family is completely invariant to the $Y$-transformation.

Note that when printing the result of `orm` the intercepts are not printed by default.  There are options for printing them, or use `coef(fit)`.

Comment: with 20 observations pro variable, I mean that I have a min #obs = 20*#variables

Comment: I can't install package `rms` due to problems with it's dependencies, not all of them are available for `R 3.0` .
I decided to use only `lmRob` . what do you think about using `drop1.lmRob` or `step.lmRob`?

Comment: If you are running the latest version of R (and if you are using RStudio you have installed its latest version too) `rms` and its dependencies work fine.

Comment: I tried now the `orm` and it returned totally different results than `lmRob`. I still have some questions: 1. why would you choose `orm` over a robust linear method. 2. I haven't seen the coefficient for the intercept in the result, where is it?

Comment: I can't understand why are there so much values for the intercept (coef(fit)).

Comment: There is k-1 where k is the number of unique Y values.  Think of the intercepts as the empirical distribution of Y given X